# When filing an ICAO flight plan with LPV, is marking GNSS equipment necessary or redundant?

Tags: icao, equipment, flight-plans

Should equipment 'B' (LPV) and Equipment 'G'(GNSS) both be filed simultaneously in an ICAO flight plan, or does equipment 'B' simply imply GNSS?

Answer (score 1):

**You should fill both G and B.**

If I understand the last row of the official ICAO guidance correctly, field 10 (equipment code) of the flight plan must contain at least B and G if you want to fly LPV approaches:

[image: ICAO guidance]
<sup>(cropped from [ICAO Guidance for the provision of NAV/COMSUR information in the New ICAO 2012 Flight Plan](https://www.icao.int/safety/FITS/DocumentLibrary/FITS-Library/Guidance_Item%2010_18.pdf))</sup>

You will also have to enter "NAV/ SBAS" in field 18.

This is also confirmed by the following information on the ForeFlight support page:

> When specifying a PBN code, be sure to also specify **R** (Code for Performance-Based Navigation (PBN) Approved) and the associated sensors that the PBN code requires. For example, PBN Code **D2** is RNAV 1 using GPS, **therefore Equipment Code G (GNSS) must also be specified**.
>
> [...]
>
> These tables are a general aid for entering filing codes in ForeFlight and are not an authoritative or comprehensive equipment specification. **Consult the AFM or AFM supplements for your aircraft to determine which codes are actually appropriate** before attempting to file using ForeFlight. The codes listed below are in addition to the other ICAO Equipment code that may be appropriate for your aircraft.
>
> **WAAS**
>
> - GNS 430W - **R, B,** and PBN B2, C2, **D2**
> - GNS 530W - **R, B,** and PBN B2, C2, **D2**
> - GNS 480 - **R, B,** and PBN B2, C2, **D2**
> - GTN 6XX/7XX - **R, B,** and PBN B2, C2, **D2**
> - GPS 175 - **R, B,** and PBN B2, C2, **D2**
> - GNX 375 - **R, B,** and PBN B2, C2, **D2**
> - G1000, 2000, 3000, 5000 WAAS - **R, B,** and PBN B2, C2, **D2**

<sup>([foreflight.com](https://support.foreflight.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049193173-ICAO-Equipment-Guide), emphasis mine)</sup>